# How to run Docker in devcontainers on Mac M1 Apple Silicon?

Tags: docker, apple-m1, vscode-devcontainer

I'm on a project where I'm the only Mac user on the team and want to use Docker in a vscode devcontainer. I keep getting dependency issues because my architecture is different.

I've tried to set the `remoteEnv` to use the variable `DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=amd64`, which didn't work. You can't detect the operating system and do conditional `runArgs` yet https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/3972

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing is using [Rosetta](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211861), which allows apple silicon to run Intel processor apps.

I'm using [colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima) for my docker runner.
So to start Docker I run

```
colima start --vz-rosetta --vm-type vz --arch x86_64
```

It's very missable but on the Docker Install guide for Mac it shares how to install Rosetta.

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/

`softwareupdate --install-rosetta`

If all else fails just add `--platform linux/amd64` as a `runArgs` to the devcontainer. It may not break other folks'. Otherwise I'm recommending to just run a Docker container not a devcontainer.

Or in the head of the Dockerfile you could add `FROM --platform=linux/amd64 <Docker image name>`

Comment: Thank you for sharing your findings, I had very analogous problems and your answer was a saver!! I'm on Apple M chip and I needed an environment for x86... I found helpful to add to my DevContainer `"runArgs": ["--network=host"],` to reach from the DevContainer other docker containers started with Colima, and at times `"remoteUser": "root"` depending on the DevContainer base image to avoid permission issue while saving files in the remote-connected VSCode

Comment: Another nice thing to do is to enable virtiofs so that mounted directories sync faster. 3x as fast in some cases. You can do that with `colima start --vz-rosetta --vm-type vz --arch x86_64 --mount-type virtiofs` or by modifying colima.yaml for whatever host you're using for devcontainers.